# CreateProcessWithTokenW - Example of usage in C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm trying to use the `CreateProcessWithTokenW()` win32 API function to start a new process with a token. The problem is that I'm quite new to the win32 API and I have no idea how to use the function properly, and which structs etc. that are needed. Could someone provide me with an example of how to use the function correctly in C#?

Comment: Where do you want to get your token from? What exactly is driving you to this function?

Comment: I'd guess you are trying to do something like what is described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is unmanaged code so you need to use P/Invoke (Platform Invoke), here's the function signature for `CreateProcessWithTokenW()`:

```
[DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool CreateProcessWithTokenW(
    IntPtr hToken, 
    LogonFlags dwLogonFlags, 
    string lpApplicationName, 
    string lpCommandLine, 
    CreationFlags dwCreationFlags, 
    IntPtr lpEnvironment, 
    string lpCurrentDirectory, 
    [In] ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, 
    out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);
```

You can use an enum like this to pass in the `LogonFlags` param (to keep the .net feeling :) ) :

```
public enum LogonFlags
{
     WithProfile = 1,
     NetCredentialsOnly
}
```

Here's the enum for the `CreationFlags` following the documentation available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682434%28VS.85%29.aspx) :

```
public enum CreationFlags
{
    DefaultErrorMode = 0x04000000,
    NewConsole = 0x00000010,
    NewProcessGroup = 0x00000200,
    SeparateWOWVDM = 0x00000800,
    Suspended = 0x00000004,
    UnicodeEnvironment = 0x00000400,
    ExtendedStartupInfoPresent = 0x00080000
}
```

Comment: For more information, see this function on p/invoke.net:  http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/CreateProcessWithTokenW.html